# Intel xdk, the scrolling option not working on real device

Tags: intel, intel-xdk

when I am running my apps on emulator or virtual device, its working fine, but when i am running it on real device the screen not scrolling, I am using an Intel xdk bootstrap design. Please can someone tell me how I can solve this issue.

Comment: can you post your code on jsbin and paste the link, so I can look at it?

Comment: iTS , WORKING FINE IN BROWSER, BUT WHEN I MADE IT APK AND RUN TO MY PHONE ITS NOT SCROOLING, VERY BIG CODING , ALL THE BOOTSTRAP FILE THERE

Comment: did u create app using app designer in xdk? which android version/device ?

Comment: I checked my app again its working fine with android 4 or uppper version but below version not working the scrooling

Comment: see this
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26380531/intel-xdk-not-work-on-android

Comment: Hi Brad, do you find any solution for your problem with scrolling ? I am having the same problem using Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are experiencing is present in Android devices with versions below 3.0 due to the interpretation of css properties by the WebView. This is an issue related to the styling created by the Intel XDK App Designer within the index_main.less.css file. This file is auto-generated and stored within the *css* folder in your project directory every time you make changes to layout with the Designer.

*In order to resolve this issue, you will need to make changes to the following css class.*

***index_main.less.css***

```
    .......
    /*.upage {*/ /*Comment out this line*/
    .upage-outer { /*Add this line*/
       overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .......
```

You should now be able to scroll your app.

**Note: The index_main.less.css file will be re-written every time UI changes are made to the layout.**